# Redirect after login with jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, redirect, jquery-mobile

I need to redirect a user to the landing page once a user has logged in. This is my PHP code so far if the authentication is successful.

```
header("Location: $success");
```

where

```
$success = (isset($_POST['uri'])) ? '' : '/index.php';
```

However, the page redirection fails with error **Error Loading Page**. If the view is refreshed, the user is correctly logged in.

Comment: Why are you wrapping that into PHP? And why not make a header() redirect after successful login instead of making clientside scripting?

Comment: jQM doesn't use "$(document).ready(function() http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html try pageInit() instead

Comment: @Repox I was just testing it out - header doesn't work either.

Comment: @PhillPafford I've removed it.

Comment: Not saying this is the best example but http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL should give you and idea on how to go about do this

Comment: @PhillPafford, I've already got the login system done, it's just that jQuery Mobile isn't liking me trying to redirect the user to the logged in area. It just bounces back at the login page.

Comment: so if($success) { header("Location: where.index"); exit();} else { header("Location: login.index"); exit(); }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6905/discussion-between-shamil-and-phill-pafford)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a problem with my PHP, in defining $status.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old But for anyone who comes here searching for the solution.

On your login form add (data-ajax="false") attribute.
Here is how to do it:

```
<form method="post" data-ajax="false" action="loginprocess.php" id="login-form">
```

This prevents the form to use ajax for posting data to server so you get actual redirection through PHP header().

Hope this helps.